# delete record with an AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I have a MEAN Stack application. The code in my controller adds the records I expect with the `$Factory` "`postServiceById.update`". After that ends and sends a successful response the next line "`postServiceById.delete`" is not  called. The application seems to stall. `vDelete` gets back a string from the update `$factory`.

What am I missing?

**==== Angular controller ====**

```
// factory for a single event post by _id
app.factory('postServiceById', function ($resource,$q,$filter,$rootScope) {
 return $resource('/api/eveProfile/:eveTitle'
  , {'eveTitle':'@eveTitle'}
  , {
   'update': { method: 'PUT' },
   'getQuery':{method: 'GET',isArray:false}
});
});

if(response.data == 'true'){
    var vDelete;
    vDelete = postServiceById.update({},{'eveTitle':$scope.eveSingle._id,field:data, 'fieldName':field}); 
    postServiceById.delete({},{'eveTitle':$scope.eveSingle._id,'successValues':vDelete});
} else {
   console.log('You are not authorized to make this change!');
};
```

Comment: How is the `postServiceById` factory defined?

Comment: @gnerkus I added the additional info. `delete` is already defined in the factory so there isn't any need for me to declare it specifically... or so I thought.